# Cantor Ternary Set Problem, Ternary Expansions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

I'm reading Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space by Frank Jones and I'm stuck on this problem, of page 41, problem 15.

Let $C$ the Cantor Ternary Set.

Let $G_{1}=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, $G_{2}=(\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9})\cup(\frac{7}{9},\frac{8}{9})$ then $C=[0,1]-\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}{G_{k}}$

Now let $x\in C$. Prove that $x$ is an end point of some extracted interval belonging to some $G_k\Leftrightarrow$ $x$ has two different ternary expansions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If a number in $[0,1)$ has two different ternary expansions, they are of the form $0.d_1d_2\ldots d_n02222\ldots$ and $0.d_1d_2\ldots d_n10000\ldots$. Show that these numbers are the rational numbers whose denominators in lowest terms are powers of $3$. Note that this shows that only one of the two implications is actually true.

Comment: While that's correct, it shows that the exercise is nonsense: that would be true for $\frac49,$ say, which has nothing whatsoever to do with any $G_k.$

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Yep, and I really ought to warn the OP about that.

Comment: Why they are of this form?

Comment: @GabrielCanedo: For the same reason that in ordinary decimal notation $0.19999\ldots=0.2000\ldots$. Think about the geometric series that a decimal expansion or a ternary decimal expansion represents.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: But $\frac{4}{9}\not\in C$...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you for the Hint. is the only thing i needed!

Comment: @Gabriel: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Gabriel Canedo That's correct, my bad, I've overlooked the $x\in C.$ Nonetheless, this is a random property of a specific construction, a countable subset of the uncountable set of Lebesgue measure $0.$